# Getting maximum value in remaining sub-list for each element in a list

Tags: scala, for-loop, for-comprehension

```
val input = List(16, 17, 4, 5, 3, 0)
```

We have to sort in a way where starting from the first element we need to return the maximum element in the remaining list.

I want output like `17,5,5,3,0`.

I've Tried Below code

```
val v1 = input.scanRight(Int.MinValue)(math.max).dropRight(1)
println("variation 1, with scan")
println(v1)
```

Comment: How does the desired result relate to the input? Why are the `16` and `4` removed? Why is the `5` repeated?

Comment: We have to sort in a way where starting from the first element we need to return the maximum element in the  remaining list.

Comment: Your title does not match your code. Your code does not match your desired output. You want to max from the right, but you say Sorting in the title. It is not sorting, and your expected output should be `17,17,5,5,3,0`

Comment: I am new here , so Apologize for not framing it in proper manner..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you could use [`foldRight`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldRight[B](z:B)(op:(A,B)=%3EB):B) to traverse the list from right to left, and at each iteration store the maximum value of the traversed elements in the accumulator, which is a Tuple of `(List[Int], Int)`:

```
val input = List(16, 17, 4, 5, 3, 0)

input.foldRight((List[Int](), Int.MinValue)){ case (i, (ls, j)) =>
  val m = i max j
  (m :: ls, m)
}._1
// res1: List[Int] = List(17, 17, 5, 5, 3, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reversing will work in above case

```
 var max = Int.MinValue
      val buffer = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int](input.length)
      for (i <- input.reverse if i >= max) {
        max = i
        i +=: buffer
      }

    println(buffer.toList)
```